# SQL delete rows only if all values of a set of columns are equal

Tags: sql, delete-row

Considering two tables

Table a:

```
Fields :  
- a_ID1  
- a_Status     
- a_Key
```

Table b:

```
Fields :  
- b_ID  
- b_Status  
- FK_a_key
```

Is there a way to delete a group of rows from  both table regarding the following conditions:
Delete every rows where  `FK_a_key = xxx and a_key = xxx`
But Only if none of this rows has the Status field different than “2” ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of `not exists` calls should do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM a
WHERE  a_key = 'xxx' AND 
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   a
                   WHERE  a_key = 'xxx' AND a_status != 2) AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   b
                   WHERE  FK_a_key = 'xxx' AND b_status != 2)


DELETE FROM b
WHERE  b_key = 'xxx' AND 
       -- Frankly, both these conditions are are redundant - 
       -- they've been checked in the previous statement
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   a
                   WHERE  a_key = 'xxx' AND a_status != 2) AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   b
                   WHERE  FK_a_key = 'xxx' AND b_status != 2)
```